# Use Sylow $p$-subgroup to prove normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I am working on the proof of the following problem:
Let $|G| < p^{2}$ for a prime $p$.  Prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|H| = p$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup.

The brief of my proof is:

1. Let $|G|=p^{2}-m$, since $p$ divides $|G|$, $p$ divides $m$. Write $m=pk$, then $|G|=p(p-k)$. $p$ divides $|G|$ and $p^{2}$ doesn't, so $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.
2. By Sylow Theorem, $H$ is normal iff $H$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup in $G$.
3. The number of Sylow $p$-subgroup in $G$ is $1+lp$ for $l$ in non-negative integers, and $1+lp$ divides $(p-k)$. This implies the only possible $l$ is $0$. So $H$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup in $G$, so $H$ is normal.

I want to make sure my proof is valid. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly valid. Notice that the assumption $|G|<p^2$ needs not even be a strict inequality. i.e. $|G|\le p^2$ and still be fine. In this case $k$ may $=0$ and step $3$ still holds. Since you already know that a Sylow subgroup is normal iff. it is unique, I would suggest this alternative way of counting: suppose $H,K\in Syl_p(G)$ are distinct, then $HK$, a subset of $G$, would have $|H||K|/|H\cap K|=p^2$ elements, more than what $G$ can hold.